# Why can't my Nvidia Jetson Nano find my CSI Camera?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, nvidia, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano

I recently bought the nvidia jetson nano microcomputer, the 4Gb. After the first boot, I created a python environment and installed some libraries like numpy, sklearn, pytorch, pandas, etc. Afterwards, I wanted to test a pre-build model for objection recognition. To be more exact I followed Nvidia's tutorial [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bcM5AQSAzUY). Everything went according to plan and no errors, until I tried to run the programm. I think I need to specify that the following logs were the result of of the program when I ran it on both of my csi cameras: [Camera 1](https://www.amazon.de/Waveshare-Jetson-Development-IMX219-77-Accessories/dp/B085W35VHV/ref=sr_1_2_sspa?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=waveshare&qid=1614934188&sr=8-2-spons&psc=1&smid=A3U321I9X7C9XA&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUE3VFNVRTJHMjdFRTMmZW5jcnlwdGVkSWQ9QTA4MDA4NTkxUzVGTlpHQjg1SlQ5JmVuY3J5cHRlZEFkSWQ9QTA1NjU2ODNKOFdZSDBTQkFRMzAmd2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9hdGYmYWN0aW9uPWNsaWNrUmVkaXJlY3QmZG9Ob3RMb2dDbGljaz10cnVl) and  [Camera 2](https://www.amazon.de/Electreeks%C2%AE-Raspberry-Kamera-Automatik-Infrarot-Sperrfilter/dp/B08C5GDG9Q/ref=sr_1_12?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=infrared%20camera&qid=1614934223&sr=8-12)

When running it on the terminal with `python my-detection.py`. After running it, the programm stoped running. Here are the logs:

```
jetson.inference -- detectNet loading build-in network 'ssd-mobilenet-v2'

detectNet -- loading detection network model from:
      -- model        networks/SSD-Mobilenet-v2/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.uff
      -- input_blob   'Input'
      -- output_blob  'NMS'
      -- output_count 'NMS_1'
      -- class_labels networks/SSD-Mobilenet-v2/ssd_coco_labels.txt
      -- threshold    0.500000
      -- batch_size   1

 [TRT]    TensorRT version 7.1.3
 [TRT]    loading NVIDIA plugins...
 [TRT]    Registered plugin creator - ::GridAnchor_TRT version 1
 [TRT]    Registered plugin creator - ::NMS_TRT version 1
 [TRT]    Registered plugin creator - ::Reorg_TRT version 1
 [TRT]    Registered plugin creator - ::Region_TRT version 1
 [TRT]    Registered plugin creator - ::Clip_TRT version 1
 [TRT]    Registered plugin creator - ::LReLU_TRT version 1
 [TRT]    Registered plugin creator - ::PriorBox_TRT version 1
 [TRT]    Registered plugin creator - ::Normalize_TRT version 1
 [TRT]    Registered plugin creator - ::RPROI_TRT version 1
 [TRT]    Registered plugin creator - ::BatchedNMS_TRT version 1
 [TRT]    Could not register plugin creator -  ::FlattenConcat_TRT version 1
 [TRT]    Registered plugin creator - ::CropAndResize version 1
 [TRT]    Registered plugin creator - ::DetectionLayer_TRT version 1
 [TRT]    Registered plugin creator - ::Proposal version 1
 [TRT]    Registered plugin creator - ::ProposalLayer_TRT version 1
 [TRT]    Registered plugin creator - ::PyramidROIAlign_TRT version 1
 [TRT]    Registered plugin creator - ::ResizeNearest_TRT version 1
 [TRT]    Registered plugin creator - ::Split version 1
 [TRT]    Registered plugin creator - ::SpecialSlice_TRT version 1
 [TRT]    Registered plugin creator - ::InstanceNormalization_TRT version 1
 [TRT]    detected model format - UFF  (extension '.uff')
 [TRT]    desired precision specified for GPU: FASTEST
 [TRT]    requested fasted precision for device GPU without providing valid calibrator, 
 disabling INT8
 [TRT]    native precisions detected for GPU:  FP32, FP16
 [TRT]    selecting fastest native precision for GPU:  FP16
 [TRT]    attempting to open engine cache file /usr/local/bin/networks/SSD-Mobilenet- 
 v2/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.uff.1.1.7103.GPU.FP16.engine
 [TRT]    loading network plan from engine cache... /usr/local/bin/networks/SSD-Mobilenet- 
 v2/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.uff.1.1.7103.GPU.FP16.engine
 [TRT]    device GPU, loaded /usr/local/bin/networks/SSD-Mobilenet- 
 v2/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.uff
 [TRT]    Using an engine plan file across different models of devices is not recommended 
 and is likely to affect performance or even cause errors.
 [TRT]    Deserialize required 6072963 microseconds.
 [TRT]    
 [TRT]    CUDA engine context initialized on device GPU:
 [TRT]       -- layers       117
 [TRT]       -- maxBatchSize 1
 [TRT]       -- workspace    0
 [TRT]       -- deviceMemory 35449856
 [TRT]       -- bindings     3
 [TRT]       binding 0
            -- index   0
            -- name    'Input'
            -- type    FP32
            -- in/out  INPUT
            -- # dims  3
            -- dim #0  3 (SPATIAL)
            -- dim #1  300 (SPATIAL)
            -- dim #2  300 (SPATIAL)
 [TRT]       binding 1
            -- index   1
            -- name    'NMS'
            -- type    FP32
            -- in/out  OUTPUT
            -- # dims  3
            -- dim #0  1 (SPATIAL)
            -- dim #1  100 (SPATIAL)
            -- dim #2  7 (SPATIAL)
 [TRT]       binding 2
            -- index   2
            -- name    'NMS_1'
            -- type    FP32
            -- in/out  OUTPUT
            -- # dims  3
            -- dim #0  1 (SPATIAL)
            -- dim #1  1 (SPATIAL)
            -- dim #2  1 (SPATIAL)
 [TRT]    
 [TRT]    binding to input 0 Input  binding index:  0
 [TRT]    binding to input 0 Input  dims (b=1 c=3 h=300 w=300) size=1080000
 [TRT]    binding to output 0 NMS  binding index:  1
 [TRT]    binding to output 0 NMS  dims (b=1 c=1 h=100 w=7) size=2800
 [TRT]    binding to output 1 NMS_1  binding index:  2
 [TRT]    binding to output 1 NMS_1  dims (b=1 c=1 h=1 w=1) size=4
 [TRT]    
 [TRT]    device GPU, /usr/local/bin/networks/SSD-Mobilenet-v2/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.uff 
 initialized.
 [TRT]    W = 7  H = 100  C = 1
 [TRT]    detectNet -- maximum bounding boxes:  100
 [TRT]    detectNet -- loaded 91 class info entries
 [TRT]    detectNet -- number of object classes:  91
 [gstreamer] initialized gstreamer, version 1.14.5.0
 [gstreamer] gstCamera -- attempting to create device csi://0
 [gstreamer] gstCamera pipeline string:
 [gstreamer] nvarguscamerasrc sensor-id=0 ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=(int)1280, 
 height=(int)720, framerate=30/1, format=(string)NV12 ! nvvidconv flip-method=2 ! video/x- 
 raw ! appsink name=mysink
 [gstreamer] gstCamera successfully created device csi://0
 [video]  created gstCamera from csi://0
 ------------------------------------------------
 gstCamera video options:
 ------------------------------------------------
 -- URI: csi://0
 - protocol:  csi
 - location:  0
 -- deviceType: csi
 -- ioType:     input
 -- codec:      raw
 -- width:      1280
 -- height:     720
 -- frameRate:  30.000000
 -- bitRate:    0
 -- numBuffers: 4
 -- zeroCopy:   true
 -- flipMethod: rotate-180
 -- loop:       0
 ------------------------------------------------
 [OpenGL] glDisplay -- X screen 0 resolution:  1920x1080
 [OpenGL] glDisplay -- X window resolution:    1920x1080
 [OpenGL] glDisplay -- display device initialized (1920x1080)
 [video]  created glDisplay from display://0
 ------------------------------------------------
 glDisplay video options:
 ------------------------------------------------
 -- URI: display://0
 - protocol:  display
 - location:  0
 -- deviceType: display
 -- ioType:     output
 -- codec:      raw
 -- width:      1920
 -- height:     1080
 -- frameRate:  0.000000
 -- bitRate:    0
 -- numBuffers: 4
 -- zeroCopy:   true
 -- flipMethod: none
 -- loop:       0
 ------------------------------------------------
 [gstreamer] opening gstCamera for streaming, transitioning pipeline to GST_STATE_PLAYING
 [gstreamer] gstreamer changed state from NULL to READY ==> mysink
 [gstreamer] gstreamer changed state from NULL to READY ==> capsfilter1
 [gstreamer] gstreamer changed state from NULL to READY ==> nvvconv0
 [gstreamer] gstreamer changed state from NULL to READY ==> capsfilter0
 [gstreamer] gstreamer changed state from NULL to READY ==> nvarguscamerasrc0
 [gstreamer] gstreamer changed state from NULL to READY ==> pipeline0
 [gstreamer] gstreamer changed state from READY to PAUSED ==> capsfilter1
 [gstreamer] gstreamer changed state from READY to PAUSED ==> nvvconv0
 [gstreamer] gstreamer changed state from READY to PAUSED ==> capsfilter0
 [gstreamer] gstreamer stream status CREATE ==> src
 [gstreamer] gstreamer changed state from READY to PAUSED ==> nvarguscamerasrc0
 [gstreamer] gstreamer changed state from READY to PAUSED ==> pipeline0
 [gstreamer] gstreamer stream status ENTER ==> src
 [gstreamer] gstreamer message new-clock ==> pipeline0
 [gstreamer] gstreamer changed state from PAUSED to PLAYING ==> capsfilter1
 [gstreamer] gstreamer changed state from PAUSED to PLAYING ==> nvvconv0
 [gstreamer] gstreamer changed state from PAUSED to PLAYING ==> capsfilter0
 [gstreamer] gstreamer message stream-start ==> pipeline0
 [gstreamer] gstreamer changed state from PAUSED to PLAYING ==> nvarguscamerasrc0
 
 Error


 ----------


 generated. /dvs/git/dirty/git-master_linux/multimedia/nvgstreamer/gst- 
 nvarguscamera/gstnvarguscamerasrc.cpp, execute:645 No cameras available
 [gstreamer] gstCamera -- end of stream (EOS)

(python:12329): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:33:50.156: gst_mini_object_set_qdata: assertion 
'object != NULL' failed
```

I tried running cheese webcam,but the screen displayed "No Device Found". That was the result with both csi cameras. The camers are csi, but when I plugged them in, the infra red one, had its lights shining, but, as I said, the camera did not work!

I am doing something wrong, do I need to do something I haven't done? Please Help me!